# Burninate [custom-backend]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[custom-backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-backend)

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

The tag is used for questions of a lot of different technologies with a lot of different meanings. The term "backend" is used rather broadly in different technologies and does not have universal meaning.

A custom backend (compared to a regular backend?) does not actual disambiguate things.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Backends and custom backends are used in various technologies, so it may be on-topic in principal, but as the term "custom backend" does not so much describe any actual concept distinct from a [backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backend) and standing on its own, it can not be meaningfully used and is thus off-topic.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. The tag does not describe much in its own. You can't be an expert in custom backends for all technologies.

Additionally, the much more active [backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backend) tag describes most of what may possibly be described by [custom-backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-backend). As such, an alternative remedy to burninating [custom-backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-backend) may be to mark it as a synonym to [backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backend).

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. It could refer to a server-side application in a website context, or a compiler backend for LLVM, or a data-processing component in a larger system or just generally a lower-level component in a software system broadest sense.

Comment: For historical purposes, the possible origin (oldest non-deleted question without/after edit) of this tag is [Do Django custom authentication backends need to take a password?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/619620/2821954) (2009), which I don't really see any info added with the existence of the tag.